# Spring data saving entities in a batch AND updating entities with JPA repository

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have a service that has a `@Transactional` method that does a lot of operations with managed entities using JpaRepositiry interfaces such as updating values and deleting entities.

On another hand in the same transactional method I have a code that creates a lot of entities in a batch

```
private void methodA() {

    ...... 
    fetch fieldsToModify and projectsToDelete
    ......

    log.debug("Modifying fields {}", fieldsToModify.size());
    issueTrackerFieldRepo.save(fieldsToModify);

    log.info("Delete projects {}", projectsToDelete.size());
    issueTrackerProjectRepository.delete(projectsToDelete);

    log.info("Adding projects {}", projectsToAdd.size());
    saveEntitiesInBatch(projectsToAdd);
}

private void saveEntitiesInBatch(List<?> entities) {
    for (int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++) {
        Object p = entities.get(i);

        log.debug("Creating entity {}", p.getClass().getSimpleName());

        entityManager.persist(p);

        if (i % batchSize == 0) {
            log.debug("Flushing entity manager for {}", i);
            entityManager.flush();
            entityManager.clear();
        }
    }

    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.clear();

    log.debug("Flushing entity manager");
}
```

where `fieldsToModify` and `projectsToDelete` are lists of entities that got fetched using jpa repository in the same method and then modified.

The problem is that when calling a batch method `saveEntitiesInBatch` all modified before entities become 'forgotten'.  This is also what `entityManager.clear()` javadoc says.

I want to have all this code run in the same transaction. How can I make batched insert and jpa repository live friendly together?